# How Is The OpenSSL Configuration File Parsed?

Tags: openssl

I'm trying to understand how OpenSSL parses its configuration file.  In the sample configuration file that is installed with OpenSSL v1.1.1g, its seems to be divided into three main sections - the `[ ca ]` section, the `[ req ]` section, and the `[ tsa ]` section (because of the lines that contain `############# ...` that separate these sections).  Inside the `[ ca ]` and `[ req ]` sections there are key/value pairs whose name is a command option and whose value "links" to another section in the configuration file.  A good example is the `x509_extensions = usr_cert` key/value pair in the `[ ca ]` section.

I am under the impression that the OpenSSL config file is processed by the OpenSSL parser starting at the first line of the file and processing the next line in turn (please correct me if that's not the case).  Therefore, I would expect the `[ ca ]` section's `x509_extensions = usr_cert` to be linked to a section of the config file that occurrs *inside* the `[ ca ]` section.  But it doesn't - it links to the `[ usr_cert ]` section that occurs inside the `[ req ]` section, which is *outside* the `[ ca ]` section.

So, what's happening when the OpenSSL parser processes the configuration file?  Is my visual perception of *inside* and *outside* wrong when I read the configuration file?  Does the parser "call" the linked section, process its key/value pairs, then return parsing of the config file to the next line in the config file?  If this is the case, wouldn't it make it ***much easier*** to understand the structure of the config file if "links" to sections that pertained to  the command whose section is being parsed were actually present within the command's section?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See man 5 config on your system or at https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man5/config.html .

I think you are being confused by your perception there is some nesting or hierarchy. There is not. ALL sections are at the same level, and are delimited solely by the `[ name ]` line. Lines consisting of `###` are comments and ignored, and used only for visual clarity to the human reader. There is a `[req]` section and a `[ca]` section and a `[usr_cert]` section and more; none of these is 'within' any other, although an item in one section *may* refer to another section -- any other section -- if the code uses it as a section name. In fact the `[ca]` section is a stub that contains *one* item that points to another section, which in the upstream config is `[CA_default]`; this allows for keeping configurations of multiple CAs (perhaps a root and intermediate(s)) in one file if desired. If we look at the code for `ca.c` relevant to your example:

https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_1_1-stable/apps/ca.c#L441:

```
    /* Lets get the config section we are using */
    if (section == NULL
        && (section = lookup_conf(conf, BASE_SECTION, ENV_DEFAULT_CA)) == NULL)
        goto end;
```

where `BASE_SECTION` is #define'd as "ca" and `ENV_DEFAULT_CA` as "default_ca", and `conf` is a variable pointing to the data structure set up by `app_load_config()` when it parsed the config file.

The variable `section` can be set by a command line option before this code is reached; if it wasn't we look in the `[ca]` section for the item `default_ca = something` and use that as the default.

https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_1_1-stable/apps/ca.c#L781:

```
        if (extconf == NULL) {
            /*
             * no '-extfile' option, so we look for extensions in the main
             * configuration file
             */
            if (extensions == NULL) {
                extensions = NCONF_get_string(conf, section, ENV_EXTENSIONS);
                if (extensions == NULL)
                    ERR_clear_error();
            }
            if (extensions != NULL) {
                /* Check syntax of file */
```

where `section` and `conf` are the variables from above and `ENV_EXTENSIONS` is "extensions". Again the variable `extensions` can be set (independently) from the commandline, otherwise we look in the selected (as above) section of the config for the item "extensions = something" and use that value.

Later in the code it passes variable `extensions` as an argument to parameter `ext_sect` of `certify()` which in turn passes it to `do_body()` which uses it as the section name in which to find information about the extensions to add. There may be many such sections, which we can select among either using the configuration or commandline options. And many of the *items* in an extension section, like `subjectAltName`, can refer to yet another config section, usually with `@name` syntax; *those* are (at least mostly) documented in [man 5 x509v3_config](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/man5/x509v3_config.html).

Comment: You've answered my post perfectly, Dave!  Your information makes it clear that there is no "section hierarchy" in the config file.  That's the issue I was trying to understand.  If you want to post this as an answer I'll give you credit.  Thanks for your time!